# ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3' arises when deploying to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have some python code, where i try to use third-party module (tweepy):

```
...
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
...
```

It's works well when i start it on the pc, but if i try to use this with google app engine, i get an error:

```
File "X:\courant\main.py", line 6, in <module>

    import tweepy

  File "X:\courant\lib\tweepy\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>

    from tweepy.api import API

  File "X:\courant\lib\tweepy\api.py", line 12, in <module>

    from tweepy.binder import bind_api

  File "X:\courant\lib\tweepy\binder.py", line 11, in <module>

    import requests

  File "X:\courant\lib\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>

    from . import utils

  File "X:\courant\lib\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>

    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

  File "X:\courant\lib\requests\compat.py", line 42, in <module>

    from .packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict

  File "X:\courant\lib\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 83, in load_module

    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))

ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
```

Tweepy is installed in /lib directory on GAE project and the link to /lib is added in code:

```
import site
import os.path

site.addsitedir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

urllib3 exists in `lib\requests\packages\urllib3` but i still get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3'
```

What am i doing wrong? I have no idea..

Comment: I assume the module that has `site.addsitedir(...)` is in the root of the project and that it gets imported before tweetpy?

Comment: Have you pip installed `tweetpy` on GAE? (`pip install tweetpy`)

Comment: @mgilson Yes, that's right!

Comment: @vishen yes, Tweepy is installed in /lib directory which is in root of GAE project

Comment: @neonhash, I am having the exact same issue, did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) to /lib (instead of using the one that comes with requests) and changing the line in compat.py from:

```
from .packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict
```

to:

```
from urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import OrderedDict
```

After that there are other libraries that you'll need to install like oauth and ssh (should be added by editing app.yaml, as Google already ships it).

Trying to test with dev_appserver.py won't work, but it will work in production if you have billing enabled (it uses Sockets).

Answer (score 3):

### Update Requests to  >= `v2.20.0`

This is no longer an issue as of `requests v2.20.0` which supports `urllib3 v1.24` - fixing this issue.

If, like me, you installed Rasbian (or whatever OS you're using) and it did not install the latest version of `requests` run

#### `pip install requests -U`

to fix the issue